# Create a FileDescriptor object on Android

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, file-descriptor, parcelfiledescriptor

I want to convert the filedescriptor (int) obtained from native to filedescriptor (Java object)

```
//native

int fd = open(......);
```

Why doesn't example 1 work? Maybe in theory?

```java
//eg 1:

FileDescriptor mFd = ParcelFileDescriptor.adoptFd(fd).getFileDescriptor();

//eg 2:

FileDescriptor mFd = new FileDescriptor()
Method setFd = FileDescriptor.class.getDeclaredMethod("setInt$", int.class);
setFd.setAccessible(true);
setFd.invoke(mFd, fd);
```

Microsoft：

> Take ownership of a raw native fd in to a new ParcelFileDescriptor.

C#

[Android.Runtime.Register("adoptFd", "(I)Landroid/os/ParcelFileDescriptor;", "")]

public static Android.OS.ParcelFileDescriptor? AdoptFd (int fd);

Parameters fd Int32
The native fd that the ParcelFileDescriptor should adopt.

Returns

ParcelFileDescriptor

**Returns a new ParcelFileDescriptor holding a FileDescriptor for the given fd.**

Attributes
RegisterAttribute

https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/android.os.parcelfiledescriptor.adoptfd?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12

Comment: 1 wouldn't work because a ParcelFileDescriptor is not a subclass of FileDescriptor.  The second I wouldn't use at all-  its relying on internal implementation details of the FileDescriptor object, which could change at any time.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan
 https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/android.os.parcelfiledescriptor.adoptfd?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12